# How to find the mean of subseries in DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My personnel side project right now is to analyze GDP growth rates per capita. More specifically, I want to find the average growth rate for each decade since 1960, and then analyze it.

I pulled data from the World Bank API("wbgapi")as a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import wbgapi as wb
gdp=wb.data.DataFrame('NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG')
gdp.head()
```

Output:
[gdp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1tE4.png)

I then used nested for loops to calculate the mean for every decade and added it to a new dataframe.

```
row, col = gdp.shape
meandata = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Country', 'Decade', 'MeanGDP', 'Region'])

for r in range (0, row, 1):
    countrydata = gdp.iloc[r]
    for c in range (0, col-9, 10):
        decade =  1960+c
        tenyeargdp = countrydata.array[c:c+10].mean()
        meandata  = meandata.append({'Country': gdp.iloc[r].name, 'Decade': decade, 'MeanGDP': tenyeargdp},  ignore_index=True)
        
    
meandata.head(10)
```

The code works and generates the following output: [meandata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lewXI.png)

However, I have a few questions about this step:

1. Is there a more efficient way to do access the subseries of dataframes?  I read that "for loops"  should never be used for dataframes and that one should vectorize operations on dataframes?
2. Is the complexity O(n^2) since there are 2 for loops?

The second step is to group the individual countries by region, for future analysis. To do so I rely on the World Bank API which has its own `Region`, which each has a list of member economies/countries.

I iterated through the regions and the member list of each region. If a `Country` is part of the `Region` list I added that region series.

Since an economy/country can be part of multiple regions(ie the 'USA' can be part of `NA` and `HIC`(high-income country)), I concatenated the region to the previously added regions.

```
for rg in wb.region.list():
    for co in wb.region.members(rg['code']):
        str1 ='-'+meandata.loc[meandata['Country']==co, ['Region']].astype(str)        
        meandata.loc[meandata['Country']==co, ['Region']] = rg['code']+ str1
```

The code works mostly, however, sometimes it gives the error message that `'meandata' is not defined`. I use Jupyter-Lab.

Additionally, Is there a simpler/more efficient way of doing the second step?

Thanks for reading and helping. Also, this is my first python/pandas coding experience, and as such general feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `groupby`:

The aggregation will be based on columns you insert inside a List of columns in `groupby` functions.

In sample below I get the mean for 'County' and 'Region'.

```
metadata = metadata.groupby(['County','Region']).agg('MeanGDP':'mean').reset_index()
```